# How to calculate Debit & Credit columns to display it each row at the 3rd column in ListView?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I tried to calculate the 2 subitems to display at the 3rd subitem or the 3rd column but it didn't work. I just don't know how. Plss help. Thanks.

(Sorry the codes are in the classroom. Forgot to copy huhu.)

-But the output looks like this in listview.

```
____________________________________
Date |Debit | Credit | Balance| User|
Jan. | 20.0 |  0.00  |        | yah |
Jan. | 12.0 |  10.0  |        | yah |
____________________________________
```

PROBLEM: Is it possible to compute
        Debit & Credit to display at the
        Balance column?? if yes, how?

INFO:

- Database is "Access" (payments)
- No "Balance" column in Access

> Sorry for lack of information

.

Comment: show your works please.

Comment: @phonemyatt I update the post. I don't know if it is enough. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping your table has an auto-number ID column.

**Design View in Access**

[image]

I am just filling a DataGridView for a quick demo.

**My data**

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strSql = "Select ID, [Date], Debit, Credit,  
                    (Select Sum(Debit - Credit) 
                    From MyLedger 
                    Where ID <= ML.ID) As Balance, User
                  From MyLedger ML;"
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessLedger)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSql, cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

The database does the work. In the Select statement we create a new field to be downloaded called Balance. This is not created in the database, just in the result set. This is done with a sub-query that gets the sum of the debit column minus the credit column but only where the ID column is less than or equal to the Id currently being retrieved. The ML is the alias for the MyLedger table and must be used to distinguish between the selection of IDs and the currently retrieved ID.

**Here are the results in the DataGridView**
[image]

Of course you would want to pretty up the results with formatting.